# How to control browser cache expiration when serving SPA from wwwroot in ASP.NET Core App

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We are serving the production bundle of an Angular based SPA from the wwwroot folder of an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Backend.
This ASP.NET Core Web Backend otherwise just acts as a REST API for the SPA.

To do so, in Startup.cs i added this line to the ConfigureServices method:

```
 services.AddSpaStaticFiles(config => config.RootPath = "wwwroot");
```

and this to the Configure method

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "wwwroot";
            });
```

This works but i noticed when i update the bundle in the wwwroot, the clients not always pick up the new version. Often they have to force refresh the page i the browser to get the latest version.

AFAIK this has to do something with the browser cache.

How can i control expiration of that cache when i deploy a new version of the SPA bundle so the new version gets picked up by the client browser immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code to clear the cache

```
      app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                    headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                    {
                        Public = true,
                        MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
                    };

                }
            });


     app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions()
                {
                    OnPrepareResponse = ctx => {
                        var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                        headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                        {
                            Public = true,
                            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
                        };
                    }
                };

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

Comment: To me, this seems to just disable caching at all. I dont see how this answers the question?